# Installing USB in LXDE

Tags: usb, lxde

I installed LXDE desktop on Ubuntu 14.04 but I cannot see my usb in LXDE Ubuntu when I plug it in. Howcan I auto detect my usb?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may not be auto mounting.  In file manager (PCManFM) go to  edit > preferences > volume management.

To show mounted volumes on the desktop go to menu > preferences > Desktop Preferences > Desktop Icons.